# How to get an intuitive value for regression module evaluation?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, model-evaluations

For regression module evaluation, I think only the `MAE` (Mean absolute error) value is not objective or practical.
 Consider following situations:

- A
  MAE=1 while target value follows the uniform distribution on the interval [1,100]
- B
  MAE=1 while target value follows the uniform distribution on the interval [1,10]

Obviously **A model** is better.

So how to get an intuitive value for regression module evaluation, **regardless the data set's target value's scope**?

Comment: You described a metric of model precision to us. What kind of answer do you want?

Comment: "Obviously B model is better" - not obvious to me at all. If I rescale the interval [1,100] to [1,10], the MAE is only approximately 0.1. I can't quickly see if comparing models on different datasets is meaningful. To me, for a fixed dataset, R^2 is just a way to see how much better a predictor is than the simple average. Similar for your value, except that for MAE the mean is not so natural mathematically, perhaps even worse than [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation).

Comment: @DavidDale , To get a intuitive value, indicating how many times the model better than another model which always predicts mean value.

Comment: @Valentas . Sorry, I was  careless.  
I edit my post and give my own answer. Please make an remark.

Comment: have you tried using MAPE instead of MAE?

Comment: @Toros91, I know this. Most target value in my data set are **zero**, so this measure is not  applicable.

Comment: oh then MAE is better, just wanted to know this reason. do mention that in question for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

To get an intuitive contrast, I came up with:

Refer to 
$$R^2=1-\frac{\sum ( y_i - \hat y_i)^2} {\sum (y_i - \bar y)^2}$$

My method is:
$$My Value=\frac {\sum |y_i - \bar y|} {\sum | y_i - \hat y_i|} $$
Indicating how many times the model better than other model, always predicts mean value.